# Xamarin Mac / XCode Unexpected Menu Items in Main Menu

Tags: c#, xcode, macos, xamarin, monomac

So here's a weird quirk I'm experiencing. Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, or what secret switch I'm missing.

I'm developing a Desktop App in Macmono / Xamarin. I edit the mainmenu.xib in XCode and then run the app from Visual Studio and some of the menu items are duplicated, and not as they should be based on the design in Interface Builder.

This is **not** an issue of synching between XCode and Xamarin, as I am able to make other changes to the menu and those work as expected when the app runs.

I do understand that Mac, or Xamarin, or something in between does automatically add some common menu items to the menus, even if they aren't present in Interface Builder.

The issue is that some of the items which are being automatically added to the Window menu are **also** being added to my custom menu (Sequence) resulting in **duplicated** menu items where they shouldn't be.

[Sequence Menu in XCode Interface Builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Aoo.png)

[Sequence Menu when App is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvudx.png)

[Window Menu when App is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSzrN.png)

The **Tile Window to Left of Screen** and **Tile Window to Right of Screen** menu items which do not exist in interface builder are being added **and** duplicated in **both** menus. The menu items representing the two open windows are also visible in both menus, when they shouldn't be.

I unfortunately have no code to share, because there is no code in the project which would be causing this.

Is this a bug/quirk in XCode or Xamarin? (Which I wouldn't doubt) Or is there some secret trick that I am not aware of that I should be enabling/disabling/implementing? Is there some code that I should add which will prevent this behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you mean the behavior is different between Xcode and VS for Mac?

Comment: No, I mean that what I design in Interface Builder is NOT what happens when I run the app.

Comment: Okey, could you share a sample project link here when you have time? I will check that in my local site.